# "In your own words" Questions - Are they considered constructive?

Tags: discussion, flagging, improvement

Considering [this question - *Explain Big O notation in your words*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14682/explain-big-o-notation-in-your-words), are questions in this form considered constructive ? There are quality answers, but in the end, everyone has their own words to describe something. Questions like this have a good chance to end up with a plethora of different answers that basically tell the same thing. Would there be a way to improve this kind of question ?

N.B. : As pointed out in the comments of the question, an [alternative version of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o) exists as well on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like it could be a homework question!

Actually on reading it now it certainly reads like a homework/interview question.

I think you've identified the problem with this type of question in that it will end up with a "plethora of answers" each pretty much as valid as the next. In addition there doesn't seem to be a real problem to be solved here.

I've now closed that question. If you have any others flag it for moderator attention - or better still cast a close vote yourself (assuming you have enough rep).

Comment: Thanks Chris :)

Answer (score 4):

IMO it's condescending form of question. Whose words would you use if not your own? Are you a plagiarizer? An android? Or maybe they want you to make up something ridiculous?

I can't remember the last time I was asked such a question, but if anyone did ask me one, I'd chafe at it.